# Is “have you found” grammatically correct?

Tags: present-perfect

I am reading one example of present perfect tense:

> Have you found your keys yet?

To form the present perfect tense join *have* or
*has* to the past participle of the verb:

- have + past participle
- has + past participle

So past participle of *found* is *founded*.

Can anyone clear my doubt?

Answer (score 2):

The past tense of the verb *found* is *founded*, but only when the verb *found* means “establish" or “begin":

> This town was founded in 1730.
>    My grandfather founded our family business after moving here from Italy.

The other sense of the word *found* is the past and past participle of the verb *find*, meaning to “discover” or “locate”:

> I found my keys under my jacket.
>   We found oil while drilling in those fields over there.

So your sentence ("Have you found your keys yet?”) is indeed grammatically correct.

You can find both meanings of *found* listed in online dictionaries such as [this one](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/found).

Comment: There's also the adjective "founded", as in "His game is founded on power and determination".